# Why does acid react with skin

Tags: acid-base, biochemistry

**Why does acid reacts with skin??**

I can understand the acid would react with blood as it is alkaline in nature. But when i googled pH of skin, its around 4-5, **"it is estimated that the 'natural' skin surface pH is on average 4.7, i.e. below 5"**([Reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18489300)) The thing that i could guess is that only *H<sup>+</sup>* are the ions that would react with our skin since only *H<sup>+</sup>* are common in every acid. But since our skin is also acidic how will an acid react with another acidic material

Comment: The shortest answer I could give is that not every molecule in a skin cell is acidic. Many biomolecules are also prone to hydrolysis under strongly acidic conditions

Comment: but what about dil. sulfuric acid or dil. acetic acid. acetic acid is even less acidic but there is still burning sensation with a bit if conc. acetic acid

Comment: 1 molar (that is: dilute) sulphuric acid still has a pH of approximately zero, so for sure it will react somehow. Acids can react with much more than ‘just’ alkaline solutions.

Comment: isn't the question narrow enough to answer??? it is as simple that "why does acid reacts with our skin to give burns?" :(

Comment: Acids first participate proteins in the skin to form a barrier.  Alkali compounds tend to digest tissue and penetrate deeper into the skin/body.